# Subquery to join conversion

Tags: postgresql, join, left-join, inner-join

How do I convert this with a query to inner join or any kind of join? this query is working fine with WITH in SQL.

> ```
> with trr as(SELECT DISTINCT td.* FROM "groups" g inner join
> "territoryDetails" td on td."groupId" = g.id where g."orgId" = 13),
> tdd as(select trr."groupId" from contacts c inner join trr on
> ST_Intersects(trr.points,c."geoPoint") where c.id = 567 and
> c."orgId"=130) select * from tdd;
> ```

Comment: What is your actual question here?  If you already have a valid working query, then what is the issue?

Comment: @Harsh Unrelated, but: the `distinct td.*` is a code smell. This should be replaced with a more efficient EXISTS condition between territorydetails and groups.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your current CTE based query actually *is* already using joins, but I suspect that the use of CTEs itself is the issue here.  You could refactor the query by inlining and removing all the CTEs:

```sql
SELECT trr.groupId
FROM contacts c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT td.*
    FROM groups g
    INNER JOIN territoryDetails td ON td.groupId = g.id
    WHERE g.orgId = 13
) trr
    ON ST_Intersects(trr.points, c.geoPoint)
WHERE
    c.id = 567 AND c.orgId = 130;
```

Comment: thank you.. it worked.. and i learnt something new!!